# Express route with /?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to route 2 different requests.

1. `/api/heroes/:id`
2. `/api/heroes/?name=`

So using nodejs and express I write the server to handle this request.
To handle the first request I write below code:

```
app.get('/api/heroes/:id', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
```

To handle the second request I write as below:

```
app.get('/api/heroes/name', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
```

But only the first handle working as expected. The 2nd request is handled by:

```
app.get('/api/heroes', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
```

How do I change the code so the second handle can work?

Comment: Unrelated to you question, but why do you have a `jsonParser' middleware for a router of a `GET` request. While it is not invalid to for GET to have a body `a payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;`

Comment: Sorry, that's bad habit, for simplicity. I just use it for GET, POST.

Comment: You really should get rid of that habit. You should add middlewares only for those routes that really make use of that. So add body parsing middlewares only for those routes that read the body.  That makes your code not only easier to maintain but also more secure.

Comment: Well received... Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly got your question, then probably you asking why req for `/api/heroes/?name=` is handled by `/api/heroes`.

You are trying to send query string parameter in 2nd req which will be handled by route `/api/heroes`. You will get query string parameter in `req.query` object.

So, your first request handler will work for urls - `/api/heroes/:id` (eg - /api/heroes/123) as follow:

```
app.get('/api/heroes/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.param.id
}
```

and for 2nd req: `/api/heroes?name=` (eg - /api/heroes?name=abc)

```
app.get('/api/heroes', function (req, res) {
  var name = req.query.name
}
```

Refer here [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 2):

This is what is expected:

For query parameters `/api/heroes/?name=` is handled by

```
app.get('/api/heroes', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
```

What you can do is to check if `req.query.name` is `undefined` then act as normal or act with the query. Using `if...else` condition.

> `/api/heroes/name` is the endpoint with `name`.

You can differentiate if you want as below:

```
app.get('/api/heroes/name/:text', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
```

Comment: If I use "app.get('/api/heroes/name/:text', jsonParser, function (req, res) {", then I have to change the request to "/api/heroes/name/?name=" right?

Comment: Right. If you want to differentiate. You can handle it by `req.query` too. But then you should have certain `if else` condition.